# Getting error while exporting azure db using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, export, powershell-cmdlet

Followed Export SQL database example using link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export-powershell#export-sql-database-example

Getting below error:

New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport : ResourceNotFound: The Resource 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/XXX.database.windows.net/databases/[DBNAME]' under resource group 'Default-SQL-SoutheastAsia' was 
not found.
At [FilePath]\sample.ps1:24 char:18
+ $exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport –ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ImportExport.Cmdlet.NewAzureSqlDatabaseExport

Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'OperationStatusLink' because it is null.
At [FilePath]\sample.ps1:30 char:63
+ Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.Ope ...
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ImportExport.Cmdlet.GetAzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus

Any help?

Comment: The error is telling you that the databasee does not exist, have you confirmed that it does and is accessible from the session you are running the script from?

Comment: Please include the command you used to trigger the export. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Database I am tryring to export is under "Default-SQL-SoutheastAsia" resource group. I am using below command: 
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport 
-ServerName "xxxxx.database.windows.net" 
-AuthenticationType Sql 
-AdministratorLogin "xxx@xxxxx" 
-DatabaseName "xxxxx" 
-StorageUri "https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxx"
-StorageKey "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==" 
–ResourceGroupName "Default-SQL-SoutheastAsia" 
–StorageKeytype "StorageAccessKey"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this same issue today, actually. I think if you change your server name to not use the fully-qualified name, that might do it. So, just use "xxxxx."

At least that's what worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I had been working on it for several hours with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify that your Automation account has latest modules imported and are up to date (AzureRM.Automation – AzureRM.Profile – AzureRM.Sql) atleast to Version: 2.5.0. If modules show a different version, i.e. 1.0.3 then:
navigate to assets in the automation account, select modules and click on 
**Update Azure Modules**

.
[image: Update the Azure PS modules]

Wait for the modules to get updated it normally takes a few minutes